# Compare the topologies $\tau$ and $\tau^{*}$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X, \tau )$ be a topological space and $S \subset X$. Show that
>   $$\tau^{*} =\{ \emptyset , G \cup S \mid G \in \tau \}$$
>   is a topology on $X$ and compare $\tau$ and $\tau^{*}$.

I think I managed to prove that $\tau^{*}$ is a topology on $X$. However, I'm not able to compare both topologies in any direction.

Let's sat I take $U\in \tau^{*}$. Then, if $U$ is not the empty set, $U =G\cup S$ for some $G\in \tau$, but I don't see why it should $U$ also belong to $\tau$' since $S$ need not be open in $(X,\tau)$.

If I take $U \in \tau$ instead, then $U \cup S \in \tau^{*}$, and though $S \in \tau^{*}$ since $S= \emptyset \cup S$ but it doesn't force $U$ to be in $\tau^{*}$.

Then I thought both topologies are uncomparable, but then Inshould come out with an example to prove it, and I couldn't find any, so I'd really need some help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an attempt to compare them, consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ (with $\tau$ being the standard topology) and $S=[0,1)$. Then  $S\in\tau^*$, but $S\notin\tau$.  Also $(1,2)\in\tau$, but $(1,2)\notin\tau^*$, so they are not comparable.

Note that if $S$ is in $\tau$, then $\tau^*\subset\tau,$ and if $S=\varnothing$ then the two topologies coincide.